# preg_replace to strip out non-printing characters seems to remove all foreign characters as well

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regex to strip out non-printing control characters from user input before inserting the values into the database.

```
 preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $value)
```

Is there a problem with using this on utf-8 strings? It seems to remove all non-ascii characters entirely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you aren't treating the target as a UTF-8 string; you need the `/u` modifier for that.  Also, in UTF-8 any non-ASCII character is represented by two or more bytes, all of them in the range `\x80..\xFF`.  Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\p{Cc}+/u', '', $value)
```

`\p{Cc}` is the Unicode property for control characters, and the `u` causes both the regex and the target string to be treated as UTF-8.

Comment: Will it leave valid characters outside of the ASCII range, like the Polish diactric characters (like ąęćśńżź)? I'm looking for a regular expression that will strip invalid UTF-8 sequences (so MySQL won't complain while inserting such a string into the database), but leave everything else untouched.

Comment: I think for that you would want to use `'/\P{Any}/u'` - `Any` should be self-explanatory, and `\P{}` (uppercase) is the negated form of `\p{}`.  But I'd be more concerned with how those invalid byte sequences got in there in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s]/u','',$value);
```

(Do add the other classes you want to let through)

If you want to revert unicode to ascii, by no means fullproof but  with some nice translations:

```
echo iconv('utf-8','ascii//translit','éñó'); //prints 'eno'
```

Comment: NOTE: The above URL is broken and SO won't let me edit the answer; correct URL is: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php